# Embed Google Maps in UIView with correct Frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, uiview

In my iOS application, I have a parent `mapViewController`(UIView) to which I try to add to Google Maps subview by executing `[self.mapViewContainer addSubview:mapView_];`

While initialising the mapView_, I try to use the bounds of the container UIView, so that it utlisises the entire space by executing:

```
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.mapViewContainer.bounds camera:camera];
```

While the map appears just fine, whenever I try to center the map on coordinate, the cordinate which is supposed to be centered is either at the bottom right, or bottom center, depending on potrait / landscape mode.

My impression is that the map extends beyond the intended margins, which I'm unable to fix.

Is there any way to easily accomplish what I'm trying to do. I have tried initialising mapView_ as

```
GMSMapView *mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

But that just displayed an empty screen.

Answer (score 0):

following line google map not shown because you use CGRectZero.so that's why not display your google map.

```
GMSMapView *mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

This code work for me...you may be helped..

See my code...you show your google map in view controller.

```
 GMSCameraPosition *camera ;

if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
{
     camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:<pass your latitude>
                                                            longitude:<pass your longitude>
                                                                 zoom:17];
}
else
{
    camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:<pass your latitude>
                                                            longitude:<pass your longitude>
                                                                 zoom:16];
}


GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height)   camera:camera];
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;


if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
{
    [mapView setMinZoom:17 maxZoom:23];
}
else
{
     [mapView setMinZoom:16 maxZoom:20];
}


// [mapView setMinZoom:16 maxZoom:20];


// mapView.settings.indoorPicker =YES;

GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(<pass your latitude>,<pass your longitude>);
marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
marker.title =@"Driver's location";

marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GoogleIcon"];
marker.map = mapView;

[self.view addSubview:mapView];

[self.view insertSubview:self.btnRefresh aboveSubview:mapView];
```

Comment: It produces the same result as mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.mapViewContainer.bounds camera:camera];

Answer (score 0):

You can place Google Map View in storyboard if possible.

If you want to do in code, avoid using frame, try use constraints.